# What happens when loading multiple numbers into a Register?

Tags: assembly, avr

I'm a bit stumped with what occurs when you load multiple values into a single register.

i.e.

```
ldi r18, 28
ldi r19, 24
mov r16, r17
ldi r19, 12
ldi r19, 122
ldi r18, 42
mov r19, r18
mov r18, r19
```

does ldi just add numbers together?
does mov replace values in the register?

what would be the final value in r18 and r19?

these aren't the exact code being requested but I'd like to better understand

Comment: What does this question have to do with C#?

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?  Why is this tagged as C and C#?  There is neither C nor C# in your question.

Comment: It's for a microcontroller, they're saying that we will focus on C following this, so I assumed it had some relation to C more than just assembly. My bad

Comment: What code are you showing? Who wrote it? Do you know what it is supposed to do? What experience do you have with writing values somewhere in programming, e.g. in C or C#? I ask because the question is confusingly unaware of those mechanisms. What happens if you set your wrist watch to different times? First to 8am then to 9am? What time does it end up with?

Comment: It is impossible to give a correct answer without knowing what architecture you are programming for.  However, in general instructions like “move data” and “load immediate” overwrite the destination register with their source.  Find out what architecture you are programming for and look up the instructions in question in the instruction set reference!

Comment: I don't really know, this is the first week of the class and i'm trying to understand what occurs with this assembly code

Comment: we're programming for an AVR microprocessor

Comment: @Mr.Student.exe That's a good start!  Do you know which specific model of AVR it is?  Atmel has two architectures: AVR8 and AVR32 as far as I know.

Comment: AVR8. I'm just lost with loading multiple numbers into one register, does it add or are there just multiple numbers? and does mov replace the values in there?

Comment: @Mr.Student.exe To add numbers, you'd use an addition instruction.  `ldi` loads a number, replacing the contents of the register with the new number.  Read the [instruction set reference](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf)!

Comment: right and mov just replaces the contents of one register with that of another?

Comment: im just confused cause I continually see ldi r17, 23 followed by ldi r17, 184. That just means the only value is 184 or does it create a stack?

Comment: I mean it could also be that I misunderstood what the instruction does (I am not familiar with AVR); read the instruction set reference to find out!

Comment: @fuz: `ldi` does just set the register to the immediate value, just like MIPS `li $t0, 123`.  AVR is an 8-bit RISC.  It doesn't make sense to have back-to-back `ldi` into the same register if you're not reading it between LDIs, for something you couldn't have done directly with an immediate.  Could be a sign of disassembling data as code, or inefficient code.  IDK if there's any way a branch target could explain it; probably not; I think you'd need to have an interrupt fire between the instructions so execution doesn't reach the second for this to be interesting.

Comment: @Mr.Student.exe: You could test this for yourself by single-stepping it in a debugger and watching register values change.  That would rule out your addition guess right away.  Your register-stack guess is best ruled out by reading the instruction-set manual.  A debugger only shows a single value for each register with no way to get a stack of values, but without other evidence you'd worry that maybe you just didn't know where in the UI, or a missing feature.

Answer (score 3):

`ldi` instruction just loads immediate data into a register. I.e. it overwrites content of the register with a new value.

```
ldi r18, 28 // now value in r18 is 28
ldi r18, 42 // now 42
```

if you want to add values, then you have to use `add` (add a value from a register), `adc` (add with carry). There is no instruction to add immediate value. Instead you can use `subi` instruction and subtract 2-complement number. E.g:

```
ldi r18, 28 // r18 = 28
subi r18, (256 - 42) // now r18 == 70
```

Note: `subi`, as many other instructions with immediate argument, accepts only registers in range r16-r31.

or you can load the value in another register and use `add`:

```
ldi r18, 28 
ldi r19, 42 
add r18, r19 // now r8 = 28 + 42 == 70
```

Read more in [AVR Instruction Set Manual (pdf)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf)

Answering your questing:

```
ldi r18, 28     // r18 = 28
ldi r19, 24     // r19 = 24
mov r16, r17    // r16 = unknown value from r17
ldi r19, 12     // r19 = 12
ldi r19, 122    // r19 = 122
ldi r18, 42     // r18 = 42
mov r19, r18    // r19 = r18 (= 42)
mov r18, r19    // r18 = r19 (= 42)
```

both `r18` and `r19` now contains value 42